# Template of email for contacting notable Skeptics

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I am working on contacting notable Skeptics to ask them to support our site.

Can you please review the email template and suggest enhancements?

---

[Skeptics http://sstatic.net/skeptics/img/logo.png](http://sstatic.net/skeptics/img/logo.png)
Hello $NAME,

I write to ask for your help in promoting the [Skeptics Q&A site](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com).

> **Skeptics - Stack Exchange** is for skeptics, rationalists, free thinkers, or anyone who questions pseudoscience. Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it's for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. It is not for philosophical discussions about skepticism itself.

We are a young but **very strong community of skeptics**, answering questions with *well-referenced answers*. We stole a page from Wikipedia's book: with us, it's *[citation needed]*.

The site is free to use and all the content is freely shareable and modifiable via a [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

### Some good questions you can find on Skeptics

- [Does a car with a hybrid engine and Lithium batteries pollute more than a car with conventional technology?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/351/does-a-car-with-a-hybrid-engine-and-lithium-batteries-pollute-more-than-a-car-wit)
  *The answer shows in-depth research on a complex topic. The result is a very complete and authoritative answer.*
- [What is the most realistic estimate for how far the Vikings could have explored the western hemisphere?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/what-is-the-most-realistic-estimate-for-how-far-the-vikings-could-have-explored-t)
  *The question offers a number of theories with links to sources describing those theories in more detail. The single submitted answer does an admirable job of addressing the question.*
- [Was Einstein a poor student?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/956/was-einstein-really-a-poor-student)
  *Often said, but the first time I saw it questioned. Proved to be extremely popular.*
- [Does being cold increase your chances of catching the common cold?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/88/cold-and-catching-colds-temperature-and-disease)
  *The question is about a very well known idea, but questioning it skeptically is fresh and novel. Also the answer is well researched and good quality.*
- [Is popping your knuckles bad for you?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/is-popping-your-knuckles-bad-for-you)
  *A surprisingly fresh question with a great answer - including a hilarious reference to the IgNobel prize.*

### How can you help us?

You can help us by participating in the community or providing exposure to the site via your blog, Facebook page or Twitter feed:

- **You can [come to our site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) and participate in the community.** Other sites of the Stack Exchange family have become friendly homes for notable experts in their respective fields.
- **You can [ask us questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).** We have a proven track record of providing great answers! 97% of asked questions have a quality answer.
- **You can publicly link a question or two on our site, through an article, blog post or tweet.**
- **You can send traffic to the site in general by reviewing the site or linking to it.**

I really hope to hear back from you. Our community and I are at your disposal for *any question* — do not hesitate to get in touch for more information if you need it.

Kind regards,

First Name and Last Name
*User or Moderator*
**Skeptics - Stack Exchange**
http://skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: By thew way, I will try to gather email addresses from notable skeptics at TAM and will follow up with this.

Comment: Did this effort ever pay off, the inquiring minds want to know?

Comment: @DVK we got a [mention](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/07/03/astronomy-stack-exchange/) by Phil Plait and a not-so-great tweet by Simon Singh.

Answer (score 4):

I would expend a bit on here:

> We are a young but **very strong community of skeptics**, answering questions with *well-referenced answers*.

Maybe into:

> We are a young but **very strong community of skeptics**, answering questions with *well-referenced answers*. We stole a page from Wikipedia's book: with us, it's *[citation needed]*.

I think that stressing the fact we require solid evidence is key. That's what really distinguishes us from every other forum and Q&A site: we ask that people back up their answers with facts. I think that's what is going to attract skeptics. It's our #1 feature.

Comment: Included in template.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to this, I'd also strongly recommend following the advice I outlined here:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/

Comment: Indeed. Now, if I only could [search my twitter lists](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14355/searching-my-twitter-lists), it would be very helpful for that! :)

Answer (score 3):

A bit late answering here, but I'd suggest that if anyone *does* send this template to a notable blogger, they mention it here. It wouldn't give a very good impression to have several people send the same mail to the same person..

Answer (score -2):

Maybe include a section about flair, probably the best way for them to promote us on their blog/home page etc

Comment: Something like: "You can become a user and add a flair to your public page (example)"?

Comment: The flair is more for established users, it's of no use to someone who hasn't heard of Stackexchange yet. I don't think we should talk about that in the first mail.