# Whatever became of "The Best of Skeptics" answers?

Tags: discussion

Over a year ago, we had a [Best of Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/4020) post, asking for nominations for 'the best of Skeptics' questions, with the intention of using these to promote the site.

I am wondering whatever happened to these posts.  What promotion occurred?  Was it successful?

The new Islam.SE site is toying with a similar [promotion](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/29), and I'm also wondering if it might be worth doing the same thing on other sites.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I personally used them:

- I sent multiple [emails to notable skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/template-of-email-for-contacting-notable-skeptics) including the top ones as examples of the content
- I use them on the [Skeptics Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/skeptics.se) to provide extra content to the feed

More in general, I think they were quite useful as an example of good content for the community at large.

If other people used them as well, I'd also be happy to hear more :-)